# Code Assist in RopeVim...how do you use it?

Tags: python, django, vim

It is not obvious to me how to use [RopeVim](http://rope.sourceforge.net/ropevim.html)'s code assist feature.
I was using Vim at the terminal in mac os x.
I moved to MacVim and the GUI does help b/c I do see a Ropevim menu option now.
I have Ropevim set up correctly I'm fairly sure.

I want to test the code assist feature out, so I type in `self.asser`
and nothing happens.  I've tried tab and control + space.

I sometimes see basically a history of what I've typed, more along the lines of auto-complete, b/c I have a plugin for that, but I want to see that code assist shows me what possible options are.

When I type in `from django.contrib.`

I want to know if code assist will be able to show me things like mail, syndication, etc, modules that I've never even typed in this project before.

Of course pycharm certainly does this flawlessly, but I am still partial to vim.  Can't quite let it go, but most definitely can not afford the time to continue to fiddle with this tinkering b/c I need to get coding. The Rope library seems like it can do what I need: code assist and basic refactoring, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use jedi-vim and code assist works perfectly. https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim.

Update:

I uploaded a short video. http://youtu.be/5lgbV8iY8-Q

Comment: I used to use rope but there are few problems which I could not resolve after that I found jedi. This is a great project. I have my repository with vim configs and a set of plugins for python development but this is for ubuntu https://github.com/kaygorodov/.vim

Comment: Thank you so much for uploading this! This is EXACTLY what I want.

Comment: jedi-vim is awesome. I tried many python/django plugins for vim, but this is the only one that actually works. my remmendations ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [the code](https://github.com/python-rope/ropevim)? Code assist seems to be mapped to `<M-/>`.